# Trying to set height of a css bracket around React 'cards'

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a page that is a tab in a database entry application. The user selects one of 3 treatment options and creates a data card for each. They are then grouped together by type. I am trying to create a bracket on the left side of the screen around each type to make it visually easier for the user. The issue I have is getting the bracket height to be a certain percentage of the card group; instead it seems to be defaulting to the percentage of the viewport. Ideally it would be 100% of each card group.

This is the css code for the bracket:

```
.grouping-vertical-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 60%;
  border: 2px solid #074153;
  position: absolute;

  .vertical-text {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 25px 25px 0px;
    margin-top: 250px;
  }
}

.grouping-horizontal-line {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #074153;
}

.patient-input-card-container {
  height: auto;
}
```

This is the code for the html (with some jsx):

```
<div className="patient-input-card-container">
      <div className="grouping-horizontal-line"></div>
      <div className="grouping-vertical-line">
        <div className="vertical-text">{associationKey}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of this part]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the container to position relative.

```
.patient-input-card-container {
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. It basically made the vertical line disappear.